# Restart returned to session indicator menu after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, restart

This is the first time I'm having problems during Ubuntu upgrade.
I had previously enabled the new Unity logout/shutdown dialogs and the restart option had gone.
But now it's back again, though utterly useless, because each one leads to the same new Unity dialog: restart or shutdown.
I wonder how I can get rid of this duplicate menu option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open ***dconf Editor***
2. Go to: ***apps*** > ***indicator-session***
3. Enable ***suppress-restart-menuitem***