# Ubuntu Start menu Shutdown/Restart have the same function

Tags: shutdown, restart

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. After upgrading and fixing some things the one thing I cannot fix is that the start menu lists Shutdown and Restart and both these buttons just open a menu with shutdown and restart as options. Previously on 13.04 only shutdown was present and it opened the same menu.

Answer (score -1):

It's part of the OS. There's nothing more to it. You are asked to choose between restarting or shutting down once again. However, I think there is an answer around [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361145/restart-returned-to-session-indicator-menu-after-upgrading-to-13-10).